# bert model as model.ckpt-1400000

Tags: python, word-embedding, bert-language-model

It is the first time that I want to use BERT. I'm trying to execute this code.

```
from keras_bert import load_trained_model_from_checkpoint
config_path = './model/bert_config.json'
checkpoint_path = './model/model.ckpt-1400000'
bert = load_trained_model_from_checkpoint(config_path, checkpoint_path)
bert.summary()
```

I have a "download-model.sh" file in "model" folder like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

wget "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1jjZmgSo8C9xMIos8cUMhqJfNbyyqR0MY" -O wiki-ja.model
wget "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1uzPpW38LcS4YS431GgdG0Hsj4gNgE5X1" -O wiki-ja.vocab
wget "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1LB00MDQJjb-xLmgBMhdQE3wKDOLjgum-" -O model.ckpt-1400000.index
wget "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1V9TIUn5wc-mB_wabYiz9ikvLsscONOKB" -O model.ckpt-1400000.meta

curl -sc /tmp/cookie "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1F4b_u-5zzqabA6OfLxDkLh0lzqVIEZuN" > /dev/null
CODE="$(awk '/_warning_/ {print $NF}' /tmp/cookie)"  
curl -Lb /tmp/cookie "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=${CODE}&id=1F4b_u-5zzqabA6OfLxDkLh0lzqVIEZuN" -o model.ckpt-1400000.data-00000-of-00001
```

when I run that code I get this error:

```
NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for ./model/model.ckpt-1400000
```

what should I do?

Comment: Try providing the absolute path.

Comment: I tried to find a file like model.ckpt-1400000 on internet or a link to it, but I couldn't find. could you please help me with that?

Comment: First, you have to download the pretrained BERT model.
The models are available here: https://github.com/google-research/bert

Comment: after downloading one of those models, the absolute path of that model will be checkpoint path?

Comment: It can be relative path as well, but when it doesn't work, probably relative path can be wrong, hence, absolute path helps in such situation to debug.